# How to assign phone number in dialer box using phonegap?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, devextreme

I'm developing a mobile app using devextreme tool where I want to make a call on click of mobile number displayed using knockout data-bind. I tried following code.

```
<a data-bind="attr:{ href: 'tel: MobileNo'}">
```

Once I bind the mobile Number, it is not recognized by phonegap and it displays random number as "3644633766245366". But MobileNo field has value of 9549875654.

If I hardcode the number as follows, it displays the number in dialer box. Can anyone suggest me what mistake I did?

```
<a data-bind="attr:{ href: 'tel: 9876543211'}">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like `<a data-bind="attr:{ href: 'tel:'+ MobileNo}">`